# can we flip cells made by display grid?

Tags: css

I have a box and a grid system like that , I want to know , can I flip(rotateY) each cell that made by display grid ?

actually I want to make some sort of slider with flipping cell effect , I did try to do with div but I couldn't , I wonder if there is a way to do that with display grid.

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
}
```